# Defining a 2D array of structs type in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct Position Position;
struct Position
{
    int x; 
    int y; 
};
```

I want to define a new type which is a 2D array of the Position struct . How can i do that? and what's the type of the function that returns such array ?

Comment: Using `typedef` would seem prudent. Unless, of course, the dimensions of your 2D array are arbitrary.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel you was close, put a new remark / answer :-)

Comment: Position[100][100]?

Comment: @mox Cyrano de Bergerac would have said *it's a bit short*, and a compiler will say *syntax error*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare the array of struct `Position` as the array of the other primitive types (for instance, `int`, `float`, etc). You can also use the double pointer.

```
Position **p;
Position p[100][100]
```

My example below using the double pointer to manipulate the size of list of `position`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct 
{
    int x; 
    int y; 
}Position;

Position ** return_array(int m, int n) {
    Position **p = malloc (sizeof(Position *) * m);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        p[i] = malloc(sizeof(Position)*n);
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            p[i][j].x = i;
            p[i][j].y = j;
        }
    }
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    Position **pp = return_array(4, 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("P[%d][%d].(x,y) = (%d, %d)\n", i, j, pp[i][j].x, pp[i][j].y);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result:

```
P[0][0].(x,y) = (0, 0)
P[0][1].(x,y) = (0, 1)
P[0][2].(x,y) = (0, 2)
P[0][3].(x,y) = (0, 3)
P[1][0].(x,y) = (1, 0)
P[1][1].(x,y) = (1, 1)
P[1][2].(x,y) = (1, 2)
P[1][3].(x,y) = (1, 3)
P[2][0].(x,y) = (2, 0)
P[2][1].(x,y) = (2, 1)
P[2][2].(x,y) = (2, 2)
P[2][3].(x,y) = (2, 3)
P[3][0].(x,y) = (3, 0)
P[3][1].(x,y) = (3, 1)
P[3][2].(x,y) = (3, 2)
P[3][3].(x,y) = (3, 3)
```

Comment: sorry, i paste wrong my code. I edited it to `Position **pp`

Comment: Thanks, but i just show the most simple result to him. I tested with `p[i][j].x = i; p[i][j].y = j` on my PC and changed to `1 and 2` for more simple.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to define a new type which is a 2D array of the `Position` struct. How can I do that?

You can typedef a 2D-array of struct Position:

```
typedef struct Position
{
    int x; 
    int y; 
} Position;
typedef Position Postion2d[M][N];
```

where `M` is the amount of elements in the first dimension and `N` is the amount of elements in the second dimension.

[Online Example](https://godbolt.org/z/h4JN44):

```
typedef struct Position
{
    int x; 
    int y; 
} Position;

typedef Position Postion2d[4][5];

int main()
{
    Postion2d a; 
    a[0][1].x = 2;
    a[0][1].y = 5;
}
```